# Getting variable from widget in a QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlistwidget

I have a custom QWidget class called `VideoWidget`. Its source file looks something like this:

```
VideoWidget::VideoWidget(QWidget *parent, string test) :
QWidget(parent)
{

    pathname=test;
    QLabel *label= new QLabel(pathname.c_str(), this);
    //...
}
string VideoWidget::getFilePath(){
    return pathname;
}
```

In my `MainWindow` class I add the `VideoWidget` to a `QListWidget` through looping through a xml file and getting the string argument from that file like this:

```
QDomNode node = rootXML.firstChild();
  while( !node.isNull() )
  {
    if( node.isElement() )
    {
      QDomElement element = node.toElement();
      VideoWidget* mytest = new VideoWidget(this, element.attribute( "Pathname", "not set").toStdString());
      QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem;
      item->setSizeHint(QSize(150,100));
      ui->myList->addItem(item);
      ui->myList->setItemWidget(item,mytest);
    }

    node = node.nextSibling();
  }
```

This correctly fills my `QListWidget` with the `VideoWidget` where all the labels have a different value.
Now I'd like to get the `pathname` variable everytime I doubleclick on a item in the `QListWidget` like this:

```
connect(ui->myList,SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(playClip(QModelIndex)));
void MainWindow::playClip(QModelIndex index){
   QListWidgetItem* item = ui->myList->itemAt(0,index.row());
   VideoWidget* widget = dynamic_cast<VideoWidget*>(ui->myList->itemWidget(item));
   cout << widget->getFilePath() << endl;
}
```

My problem is that `widget->getFilePath()` always returns the same value for every clicked widget. It is the value of the first time I set `pathname=test;`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably mistake:

```
QListWidgetItem* item = ui->myList->itemAt(0,index.row());
```

Method "itemAt" takes x and y **coordinates**, not indexes. Use "takeItem" instead.
Next thing I want to say is that this part:

```
ui->myList->itemWidget(item)
```

is useless. You can convert "item" directly. 
And last - use qobject_cast since you use Qt. And never use dynamic_case (especially when you anyway do not check result against NULL).